# How can I render a Zend_Barcode inside a html page?

Tags: codeigniter, barcode

One of my application devoloped with Codeignitor and create a barcode using Zend_Barcode library,

reference : http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/02/21/using-zend-framework-with-codeigniter/

How can I show the barcode on codeignitor view. 
Tried as ,

```
// Only the text to draw is required
$barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'NOT-ME');

// No required options
$rendererOptions = array();

// Draw the barcode in a new image,
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw(
    'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
);

$data['barcode'] = imagejpeg($imageResource, 'barcode.jpg', 100);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($imageResource);
```

in view

```
<img src="<?php echo $barcode;?>">
```

but its fails :(

Comment: What version of Zend are you using? Newer version's have some problem's working with codeigniter.  Im guessing dependancy issue's.

Comment: Did below answer helped or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Zend_Barcode::draw('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
```

Use

```
Zend_Barcode::render('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
```

Comment: if using above script we need to add library in view or controller?

Comment: library and above code should be added in controller.

The Code before above Line : 

$this->load->library('zend');
$this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');