# codeigniter + zend barcode class

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, codeigniter-2, barcode

I integrated the Zend_Barcode class by placing **Zend** directory on *application/libraries*.

Under my controller:

```
  public function barcode_gen()
  {
    $this->load->library('Zend/Barcode/Barcode');
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
    $rendererOptions = array();
    Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
  }
```

However, this results into:

```
Non-existent class: Barcode
```

I've also read lots of tutorial but never figured out how to, some tuts are quite outdated.

Even if I followed this thread on [CI forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/166294/), no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load an external class using $this->load->library() Codeigniter puts the instance of the class in a variable named like the class loaded, so you need to access that way

Since you're then calling it statically instead, I suggested dropping the CI loader method and simply include the class:

```
public function barcode_gen()
{
   require_once('./application/libraries/Zend/Barcode/Barcode.php');
   //adjust the above path to the correct location
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
    $rendererOptions = array();
   Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
}
```

Comment: This won't work either, it would just return this error `Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Barcode' not found...` [Barcode.php](http://pastebin.com/2eQuaYZ4) pastebin

Comment: I see the class name is Barcode, try then with `Barcode::factory()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, but none either. This really confuses me.

Comment: how to print barcode in pdf, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and this is what I did to make it works (I'm using CI2 and ZF2). First, integrate CI2 and ZF2, [see this example](http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/02/21/using-zend-framework-with-codeigniter/). And include Zend Barcode namespace in my barcode_gen function

```
function barcode_gen() {
    $this->load->library('Zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode/Barcode');

    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
    $rendererOptions = array();
    \Zend\Barcode\Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
}
```

--
**UPDATE**
I'm using HMVC architecture from [this](http://somethingstatic.com/setting-hmvc-codeigniter-2-1/) and Loader class is able to load the necessary file from Zend and this is my barcode_gen

```
function barcode_gen() {
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
    $rendererOptions = array();
    \Zend\Barcode\Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
}
```

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Barcode\ObjectPluginManager' not found`. Please what versions you use? ZendF 2.2? I followed exactly what you wrote including link you posted.

Comment: I was using ZF 2.1.4,
I replaced my ZF with ZF 2.2.1 and it's still work,
Maybe I missed to write some step, let me check

Comment: I just realized I'm using HMVC architecture from [this](http://somethingstatic.com/setting-hmvc-codeigniter-2-1/) and Loader class is able to load the necessary file from Zend. I don't even have to use Zend load statement (line 1 and line 2 from barcode_gen function)

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17465367/1564365)

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that the code of Damien Pirsy ( and also others like [here](http://blog.ghostbilt.com/zend-barcodes-codeigniter/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719633/how-can-i-render-a-zend-barcode-inside-a-html-page) ) is for Zend version 1 and not version 2.
If you download version 2 then you end up with  `Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Barcode' not found`

I think it will might help others too.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
The zend barcode library is under the third party folder

```
 function gen_barcode($product_code = NULL, $bcs = 'code39', $height = 60, $text = 1) {
        $drawText = ($text != 1) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
        $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $product_code, 'barHeight' => $height, 'drawText' => $drawText);
        $rendererOptions = array('imageType' => 'png', 'horizontalPosition' => 'center', 'verticalPosition' => 'middle');
        $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::render($bcs, 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions);
        return $imageResource;

    }
```