# CodeIgniter 2 + Zend 2 library barcode

Tags: php, zend-framework2, codeigniter-2, barcode

Problem: rendering barcodes in CodeIgniter via Zend library barcode.

I googled, and also tried all tutorials on first 2 pages. I stackoverflowed and found quiet a few topics on my problem, even few are marked as answered but no luck.

Finally I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480779/1564365 but yet another error message.

error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Barcode\ObjectPluginManager' not found`

that means it is actually loading Barcode library but with error.

*sidenote*: ZF 2.2 fresh download (today), CI 2.1.3 fresh download (today)

Comment: how to print barcode in pdf, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I am forced to use ZF1.
step by step:

1. Download (Zend Framework 1.12.3 Full) from [here](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF1)
2. Unzip files and locate folder `Zend` in `./libraries` folder copy it to CI `application/libraries`
3. Create new file inside (CI) `application/libraries/Zend.php` "loader for ZF"

with code as follows

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {exit('No direct script access allowed');}

/**
 * Zend Framework Loader
 *
 * Put the 'Zend' folder (unpacked from the Zend Framework package, under 'Library')
 * in CI installation's 'application/libraries' folder
 * You can put it elsewhere but remember to alter the script accordingly
 *
 * Usage:
 *   1) $this->load->library('zend', 'Zend/Package/Name');
 *   or
 *   2) $this->load->library('zend');
 *      then $this->zend->load('Zend/Package/Name');
 *
 * * the second usage is useful for autoloading the Zend Framework library
 * * Zend/Package/Name does not need the '.php' at the end
 */
class CI_Zend
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param   string $class class name
     */
    function __construct($class = NULL)
    {
        // include path for Zend Framework
        // alter it accordingly if you have put the 'Zend' folder elsewhere
        ini_set('include_path',
        ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'libraries');

        if ($class)
        {
            require_once (string) $class . EXT;
            log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");
        }
        else
        {
            log_message('debug', "Zend Class Initialized");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Zend Class Loader
     *
     * @param   string $class class name
     */
    function load($class)
    {
        require_once (string) $class . EXT;
        log_message('debug', "Zend Class $class Loaded");
    }
}
```

and controllers method should be as follows

```
function barcode() {
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    $test = Zend_Barcode::draw('ean8', 'image', array('text' => '1234565'), array());
    var_dump($test);
    imagejpeg($test, 'barcode.jpg', 100);
}
```

Comment: how to print barcode in pdf, do you have any solution?

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisZulifqar just create new controller that creates the barcode image. Then install and use dompdf for codeigniter, and when you generate the pdf from the view, just call the controller that generates the image from the view and the image will be inserted in the pdf